# Log 404 on http.FileServer

Tags: http, go, http-status-code-404

I'm serving jpeg images from `dirPath` using `http.FileServer` with:

```
http.Handle("/o/", http.StripPrefix(
    path.Join("/o", dirPath), http.FileServer(http.Dir(dirPath))))
```

What I don't understand is how to log when a request is made for a file that does not exist. I can see `http.FileServer` returning **404 page not found** when I make a request with the browser, but not on the server console.

Comment: It doesn't log its error messages: FileServer wraps ServeContent, which is internalized here: https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L360 - you would need to re-write or inspect the ResponseWriter on its way out to log it.

Comment: Possible Duplicate to this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996767/showing-custom-404-error-page-with-standard-http-package

Answer (score 12):

The [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler)s returned by [`http.StripPrefix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) and [`http.FileServer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) do not log HTTP 404 errors. You have to extend their functionality in order to achieve what you want.

We can wrap the `http.Handler` value returned by `http.StripPrefix()` or `http.FileServer()` in another `http.Handler` or [`http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc). Once you wrapped the handler, register the wrapper of course.

The wrapper implementation will simply called the wrapped one, and once it returns, can inspect the HTTP response status code. If it is an error (or specifically HTTP 404 Not Found), can log it appropriately.

Problem is [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) does not support reading the response status code. What we can do is we also wrap the `http.ResponseWriter` and when status code is written, we will store it for later to be available.

Our `http.ResponseWriter` wrapper:

```
type StatusRespWr struct {
    http.ResponseWriter // We embed http.ResponseWriter
    status int
}

func (w *StatusRespWr) WriteHeader(status int) {
    w.status = status // Store the status for our own use
    w.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(status)
}
```

And wrapping the `http.Handler`:

```
func wrapHandler(h http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        srw := &StatusRespWr{ResponseWriter: w}
        h.ServeHTTP(srw, r)
        if srw.status >= 400 { // 400+ codes are the error codes
            log.Printf("Error status code: %d when serving path: %s",
                srw.status, r.RequestURI)
        }
    }
}
```

And the main function creating a file server, wrapping it and registering it:

```
http.HandleFunc("/o/", wrapHandler(
    http.StripPrefix("/o", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/test")))))
panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil))
```

Example output when requesting a non-existing file:

```
2015/12/01 11:47:40 Error status code: 404 when serving path: /o/sub/b.txt2
```

Comment: Gosh, wish it was less painful !