# How to custom handle a file not being found when using go static file server?

Tags: go, webserver, go-server

So I'm using a go server to serve up a single page web application.

This works for serving all the assets on the root route. All the CSS and HTML are served up correctly.

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("build"))
http.Handle("/", fs)
```

So when the URL is `http://myserverurl/index.html` or `http://myserverurl/styles.css`, it serves the corresponding file.

But for a URL like `http://myserverurl/myCustompage`, it throws `404` if `myCustompage` is not a file in the build folder.

How do I make all routes for which a file does not exist serve `index.html`?

It is a single page web application and it will render the appropriate screen once the html and js are served. But it needs `index.html` to be served on routes for which there is no file.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The handler returned by [`http.FileServer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) does not support customization, it does not support providing a custom 404 page or action.

What we may do is wrap the handler returned by `http.FileServer()`, and in our handler we may do whatever we want of course. In our wrapper handler we will call the file server handler, and if that would send a `404` not found response, we won't send it to the client but replace it with a redirect response.

To achieve that, in our wrapper we create a wrapper [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) which we will pass to the handler returned by `http.FileServer()`, and in this wrapper response writer we may inspect the status code, and if it's `404`, we may act to *not* send the response to the client, but instead send a redirect to `/index.html`.

This is an example how this wrapper `http.ResponseWriter` may look like:

```
type NotFoundRedirectRespWr struct {
    http.ResponseWriter // We embed http.ResponseWriter
    status              int
}

func (w *NotFoundRedirectRespWr) WriteHeader(status int) {
    w.status = status // Store the status for our own use
    if status != http.StatusNotFound {
        w.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(status)
    }
}

func (w *NotFoundRedirectRespWr) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    if w.status != http.StatusNotFound {
        return w.ResponseWriter.Write(p)
    }
    return len(p), nil // Lie that we successfully written it
}
```

And wrapping the handler returned by `http.FileServer()` may look like this:

```
func wrapHandler(h http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        nfrw := &NotFoundRedirectRespWr{ResponseWriter: w}
        h.ServeHTTP(nfrw, r)
        if nfrw.status == 404 {
            log.Printf("Redirecting %s to index.html.", r.RequestURI)
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/index.html", http.StatusFound)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I used `http.StatusFound` redirect status code instead of `http.StatusMovedPermanently` as the latter may be cached by browsers, and so if a file with that name is created later, the browser would not request it but display `index.html` immediately.

And now put this in use, the `main()` function:

```
func main() {
    fs := wrapHandler(http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    http.HandleFunc("/", fs)
    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Attempting to query a non-existing file, we'll see this in the log:

```
2017/11/14 14:10:21 Redirecting /a.txt3 to /index.html.
2017/11/14 14:10:21 Redirecting /favicon.ico to /index.html.
```

Note that our custom handler (being well-behaviour) also redirected the request to `/favico.ico` to `index.html` because I do not have a `favico.ico` file in my file system. You may want to add this as an exception if you don't have it either.

The full example is available on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5E9KreSsnp). You can't run it there, save it to your local Go workspace and run it locally.

Also check this related question: [Log 404 on http.FileServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017342/log-404-on-http-fileserver)

Comment: This is interesting. I'd figured out another approach where I use `http.ServeFile`. Where I first check if file exists using `os.Stat` and then serve the corresponding file or index.html. Could you also tell me which approach would be better and why?

Comment: @JeffPChacko The handler returned by `http.FileServer()` also uses `http.ServeFile()` (or parts of its implementation) under the hood, but also provides other goodies like directory listing and security to make sure no file is served outside of the given folder. If don't use `http.FileServer()`, you have to take care of these (e.g. you have to normalize / resolve tricky request paths containing `..`).

Comment: I was looking for this, thanks, but I needed to make small modification to make it work with reactjs BrowserRouter
so I changed those lines:
```
if nfrw.status == 404 {
            log.Printf("Redirecting %s to index.html.", r.RequestURI)
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/index.html", http.StatusFound)
        }
```
with this:
```
if nfrw.status == http.StatusNotFound {
   w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
   http.ServeFile(w, r, "./web/static/index.html")
  }
```
so it serves index.html normally without redirection.