# FileServer handles not found css with MIME type error instead of 404

Tags: go, fileserver, go-http

I’m running a basic `http.FileServer` to serve a static site and I’ve come across an issue where requests for css files that don’t exist are getting canceled with a MIME type error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/assets/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain')
```

Ideally, I’d prefer it to be handled with a 404 error as thats what it should actually be. Any possible work arounds I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `net/http` source code (`fs.go`):

```
// toHTTPError returns a non-specific HTTP error message and status code
// for a given non-nil error value. It's important that toHTTPError does not
// actually return err.Error(), since msg and httpStatus are returned to users,
// and historically Go's ServeContent always returned just "404 Not Found" for
// all errors. We don't want to start leaking information in error messages.
func toHTTPError(err error) (msg string, httpStatus int) {
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return "404 page not found", StatusNotFound
    }
    if os.IsPermission(err) {
        return "403 Forbidden", StatusForbidden
    }
    // Default:
    return "500 Internal Server Error", StatusInternalServerError
}
```

The file server returns a 200 with a plain text file for 404 errors. The browser tries to interpret this plain text error page as a CSS file, and throws the error.

This behavior of returning the plain text file cannot be overridden on the handler returned by `FileServer()`.

As has been pointed out already, this isn't really a bug in `net/http`.

If this behavior is undesirable for you for some reason, you can explore creating a custom  handler for 404 responses, which has been explored in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996767/showing-custom-404-error-page-with-standard-http-package). You could also use a routing library like Gorilla which has [overridable behavior](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/mux.go#L47) for not found pages.